# Regular expression to match 2 words

Tags: javascript, regex

I just need to make sure 2 words are entered into a text field. The words can contain any character with any number of spaces in between them. So essentially this format:

```
<word><any number of spaces><word>
```

In tried the following and it returns not null for more than 2 words:

```
'Hello world Something'.match(/(.*){1}\s(.*){1}/)
```

Any idea what the right REGEX will look like?

Comment: if you really mean "two words, with any number of spaces in between", then literally that? start of string, then `\w+` then `\s+`, then `\w+` again, then end of string? Why would you use `.*`? That's "any character, zero or more times". Maybe time to reread https://www.regular-expressions.info ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you might want to design an expression similar to:

```
^\b[\w-]+\b\s+\b[\w-]+\b$
```

and change the char classes (`[\w-]`) as you wish.

#### [DEMO 1](https://regex101.com/r/6zW4sH/1/)

#### Edit:

```
^\S+\s+\S+$
```

#### [DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/cENRh5/1/)

Comment: Your regex works for words, when I replace `[\w-]` with `(.+)` because i want to allow any character it no longer works :/